# Esri ArcGIS JS API Dynamically Loading Modules

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am fairly new to using Esri's ArcGIS API and I'm currently trying to build an integration for Dynamics 365/CRM. Now I have encountered an issue as I need to dynamically load different modules each time a map is rendered.

Actually loading the modules isn't the issue, The issue is the callback method's parameters from the `require` method, as I can't dynamically insert each one into the script.

I have a little workaround for this by looping through the arguments and assigning each argument to a variable depending on the `declaredClass` parameter. For example:

```
var Map, MapView, SceneView, Search;    
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var arg = arguments[i];
    var obj = arg();
    if (obj.declaredClass == "esri.Map") {
        Map = obj;
    } else if (obj.declaredClass == "esri.views.MapView") {
        MapView = obj;
    } else if (obj.declaredClass == "esri.views.SceneView") {
        SceneView = obj;
    } else if (obj.declaredClass == "esri.widgets.Search") {
        Search = obj;
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but I noticed I'm not able to create new instances of these objects. Instead, I just get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Search is not a constructor

However, I can just use the object and assign values on them to render the map without initialising a new instance of it.

Can anyone tell me if I am doing it wrong by doing it this way or if there is a better way to dynamically get these parameters?

Comment: Is it possible to create a sample where we can reproduce the same error?